# How to Add minor/major configs to Ticks

Tags: chart.js

I am using chart.js on x-axis. I want to have major minor ticks for fix fontcolor. Is there any way to either access the minor ticks, or suggestions of good ways to label more of the ticks in this chatr?

Comment: If I understand correctly you want different size fonts for the xAxis label?

Comment: @KunalKhivensara I want different fontcolor for the xAxis label by my condition

Comment: Can you try doing this https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2442#issuecomment-216511992. This needs some changes to be done in the chart.js code as well.

Comment: @KunalKhivensara I try to doing but not working (I use chartjs vertion. 2.8.0)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it.

Follow the below steps:

1. Use chart.js version 2.7.3 from `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.js`
2. Find the code helpers.each(itemsToDraw, function(itemToDraw) { at line 7899 and replace it with `helpers.each(itemsToDraw, function (itemToDraw, index) {` in chart.js
3. Find the code `context.fillStyle = itemToDraw.major ? majorTickFontColor : tickFontColor;` at line 7931 and replace it with code ->

```js
if (Object.prototype.toString.call(tickFontColor) === '[object Array]') {
  context.fillStyle = itemToDraw.major ? majorTickFontColor[index] : tickFontColor[index];
} else {
  context.fillStyle = itemToDraw.major ? majorTickFontColor : tickFontColor;
}
```

4. Pass the multiple colors in the options, the number of colors should match the xAxis label count.

```js
 xAxes: [{
          ticks: {
                  fontColor: ['red', 'grey', 'blue', 'black', 'orange', 'green'],
                 }
        }]
```

[image: The output I got]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Now I use Html 5 canvas for draw chart